# As a US citizen with Mexican parents, what steps do I need to take to become a Mexican citizen?

Tags: immigration, us-citizens, mexican-citizens

I was born in Oregon after my parents moved from Mexico. Do I need any documentation, and if so, what, to prove that I have parents who are Mexican? If I go to the Mexican consulate in Portland, do one or both of my parents need to be present?
Will I need to pass any citizenship tests about Mexican history?

Comment: I have no experience with Mexico, but my experience with other countries suggests that your Mexican parents' passports or other evidence of their Mexican citizenship will be required, as well as your birth certificate, which may need to be "authenticated" or "legalized" for international use. From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_nationality_law), it appears you'll need to show that at least one of your parents was born in Mexico. If they were, you are probably already Mexican, and you should not need to pass any tests.